C# tab order problem not working in order
In this code the tabIndex doesn't work correctly, I want the tab order to be like what is set in SetTabOrder in View.cs but the only focus changes between FolderPathInput and SearchBox, but I want when tab is pressed on FolderPathInput, focus to go to ImageBox but instead goes to SearchBox. the ImageBox is focusable with click, but tab doesn't work.

note I am just using vscode and not visual studio

If you need other parts of code, comment please.
Views\View.cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace ImageCategorizer
{
    public class View : Form
    {
        public ImageShowerView ImageShower { get; private set; }
        public CategorizerView Categorizer { get; private set; }
        private Controller controller;
        public View()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.Text = "Image Categorizer";
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 600);
            var layout = new TableLayoutPanel { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
            layout.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50F));
            layout.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50F));
            ImageShower = new ImageShowerView();
            Categorizer = new CategorizerView();
            layout.Controls.Add(ImageShower, 0, 0);
            layout.Controls.Add(Categorizer, 0, 1);
            this.Controls.Add(layout);
            // Set tab order for the form
            this.SetTabOrder();
        }
        public void SetController(Controller controller)
        {
            this.controller = controller;
        }
        private void SetTabOrder()
        {
            // Set TabIndex for the controls
            this.ImageShower.FolderPathInput.TabIndex = 0;
            this.ImageShower.ImageBox.TabIndex = 1;
            this.Categorizer.SearchBox.TabIndex = 2;
            this.Categorizer.FilteredItemsList.TabIndex = 3;
        }
    }
}



Views\CategorizerView.cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace ImageCategorizer
{
    public class CategorizerView : UserControl
    {
        public TextBox SearchBox { get; private set; }
        public ListBox FilteredItemsList { get; private set; }
        public System.Windows.Forms.Timer SearchTimer { get; private set; }
        private CategorizerController controller;
        public CategorizerView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.SearchBox = new TextBox { Dock = DockStyle.Top, PlaceholderText = "Search...", TabIndex = 2, TabStop = true };
            this.FilteredItemsList = new ListBox { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, SelectionMode = SelectionMode.One, Visible = false, TabIndex = 3, TabStop = true };
            this.SearchTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer { Interval = 250 };
            var layout = new TableLayoutPanel { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
            layout.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
            layout.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100F));
            layout.Controls.Add(SearchBox, 0, 0);
            layout.Controls.Add(FilteredItemsList, 0, 1);
            this.Controls.Add(layout);
        }
        public void SetController(CategorizerController controller)
        {
            this.controller = controller;
        }
        public void FocusFilteredItem(int itemNum)
        {
            if (itemNum >= 0 && itemNum < FilteredItemsList.Items.Count)
            {
                FilteredItemsList.SelectedIndex = itemNum;
                FilteredItemsList.Focus();
            }
        }
        public void FocusSearchBox()
        {
            SearchBox.Focus();
            FilteredItemsList.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
        protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
            {
                controller.HandleUpArrowPressed();
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
            {
                controller.HandleDownArrowPressed();
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                controller.HandleEnterPressed();
            }
        }
    }
}


Views\ImageShowerView.cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace ImageCategorizer
{
    public class ImageShowerView : UserControl
    {
        public TextBox FolderPathInput { get; private set; }
        public PictureBox ImageBox { get; private set; }
        public string DefaultImagePath { get; set; }
        private ImageShowerController controller;
        public ImageShowerView()
        {
            DefaultImagePath = "F:\\projects\\public github projects\\private repos\\hobbyCodes\\imgNVid\\imageCategorizerGui\\imageNotFound.png"; // Set the path to imageNotFound.png
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.FolderPathInput = new TextBox { Dock = DockStyle.Top, PlaceholderText = "Enter folder path...", TabIndex = 0, TabStop = true };
            this.ImageBox = new PictureBox
            {
                SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom,
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                ImageLocation = DefaultImagePath,
                TabStop = true,
                TabIndex = 1
            };
            var layout = new TableLayoutPanel { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
            layout.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
            layout.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100F));
            layout.Controls.Add(FolderPathInput, 0, 0);
            layout.Controls.Add(ImageBox, 0, 1);
            this.Controls.Add(layout);
            // Handle focus events
            this.ImageBox.Click += (sender, e) => ImageBox.Focus();
            this.ImageBox.KeyDown += ImageBox_KeyDown;
        }
        public void SetController(ImageShowerController controller)
        {
            this.controller = controller;
        }
        private void ImageBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.X)
            {
                controller.NextImage();
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Z)
            {
                controller.PreviousImage();
            }
        }
    }
}


I am just using vscode and not visual studio use Visual Studio. VS Community is free. What you ask is generated by the Forms Designer, which takes care to put the very verbose InitializeComponent code in a partial file. What you posted seems to set the TabIndex in a control that can't accept the focus

WinForms doesn't have controllers and views anyway, the design is completely different. You'll find MVVM implementations though, based on data binding, command routing and the work done for WPF, MAUI etc.

@PanagiotisKanavos vs is more 45GB, I don't want editor that big. first of all, does my code seem to be correct?

No it doesn't. Install Visual Studio and use the designer. It's NOT 45GB. You don't have to install all workloads if you only intend to use Windows Forms
